# How to use tensorflow.crop_and_resize() for quadrilaterals

Tags: c, tensorflow, image-processing, geometry

I want to crop and resize a random quadrilateral from an image defined by 8 coordinate points :

```
(xtl, ytl), (xtr, ytr), (xbr, ybr), (xbl, ybl)
```

I have [a code sample implementing the same crop and resize for a rectangle from an image, described by 4](https://gist.github.com/crazysal/3d437340f8906d6ba62b4653d1598e43#file-cropandresize-c) coordinates -

```
(x1,y1), (x2, y2)
```

I have not worked much with C but I can still understand what the code is doing till a point where it's not understandable why the author did the computations. Specifically from line 53 in above gist.

pseudocode till where I understood :

Variables Involved:

### Image -

```
 float * image_data // float pointer to image data of original tensor shape- A = `<Batch X Channel X Height X Width>`
 int batch_size // Batch value - for simplicity lets take single image A0= 1
 int depth // Channel value from above shape for rgb A1= 3
 int image_height // Height value from above shape  A2= 128
 int width // width value from above shape A3 = 128
```

That is, original image is 3 matrices of 128x128 rowsxcolumns

### Boxes -

```
float * boxes_data //float pointer to boxes coordinates in format B = `[y1,x1,y2,x2] X Number_of_Boxes`
int * box_index_data // can be ignored for our purpose B0= 0 
int start_box // starting count of box B1 = 0 
int limit_box // ending count of box B2 = 5000
```

That is, we have a list of 5000 coordinates(in pair of 4) of rectangles we want to crop from our original image.

Each crop is resized by using bi-linear interpolation to required crop dimensions.

### Crops -

```
float * corps_data //variable of all zeroes to hold final resized cropped pixels of shape - C = <5000*3*128*128> ie. 5000 matrices of original image size
int crop_height // height we wish to crop to C0 = 8 ie height of cropped box is 8 pixels
int crop_width // width we wish to crop to C1 = 64 ie height of cropped box is 64 pixels 
float extrapolation_value // can be ignored for our purpose C2 = 0
```

### Algorithm :

1. First Loop over all boxes (0 to 5000)
2. initialize current box and coordinates (box, y1, x1, y2, x2)
3. assert check box_index - can be ignored

crop is always greater than 1 for trivial case ,

4. Calculate `height_scale = (height of box) * (scale ratio between original image and crop size)`
5. Calculate `width_scale = (width of box) * (scale ratio between original image and crop size)`
6. Start second nested loop for selecting all crop pixels in column
7. Calculate in_y ??
8. --- not understood why.
9. Start second nested loop for selecting all crop pixels in column
10. Again some obscure skull treachery obfuscating code.
11. Return cropped pixel values.

Can someone please explain the concept of what is going on here ? 
I have to loop over every pixel of select part and to fill interim pixels I have to interpolate yes ??

How do I change this function to crop and resize a random quadrilateral ?

More reading :

- [High level documentation : Tensor Flow crop_and_resize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize)
- [Fast-rcnn - Object Detection Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.08083.pdf)
- [Mask-rcnn - Image Segmentation Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06870.pdf)
- [Implementation of MRCNN in pytorch](https://github.com/multimodallearning/pytorch-mask-rcnn/blob/master/roialign/roi_align/roi_align.py)

I understood the theory behind it, to remove quantization shift they sample equidistant pixels, for pixel values between grid cells it is calculated using bi-linear interpolation. These selected values are avg pooled to project on a uniform sized layer.

### Task:

Implement text align as in [this paper](http://www.whuang.org/papers/the2018_cvpr.pdf)

I want to take an input of any randomly sized and oriented quadrilateral and map it to a fixed grid size, say from an image of `128X128` I have two quadrilaterals one small like `~20x20 (box)` and one large `~80x100 (box)`. I have their coordinates. Now how to select only these pixels and project them both to a uniform size of say `64x64 (crop)`.

Comment: What is you real goal - map some non-rectangular image region into rectangle? It might be performed with OpenCV functions

Comment: Yes, i want to take an input of any randomly sized and oriented quadrilateral and map it to a fixed grid size, say from an image of 128X128 I have two quadrilaterals one small like ~ 20x20 (box) and one large ~80x100 (box). I have their coordinates. Now how to select only these pixels and project them both to a uniform size of say 64x64 (crop)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using OpenCV library.

If quadrilaterals are arbitrary (not parallelograms) - you need perspective transformations (otherwise - simpler affine transformations)

Make 4 pairs of corresponding coordinates: quad vertex - resulting rectangle vertex

Find matrix of perspective transformation:  [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga8c1ae0e3589a9d77fffc962c49b22043)

Use this matrix: **warpPerspective** or **transform**

Comment: This is good, and solves one part. I do understand how perspective transformation is done. How ever, this is a part of a neural net, I also need t calculate the gradient for the reverse computation : Gradient of bi-linear can be backprop through : 
    d(grad) / d(Vpi) = SUM{ g(px, pix) ∗ g(py, piy) }    
Hence, questioning how the fundamental code works.

Comment: But initial question told nothing about neural nets etc.

Comment: yep, it asks for an explanation of the code.  How the geometry works out. Not really another function from a package. How is the above C code doing the affine transformation, could you help me with that ?